# Angular 15: Interpolation binding throws JIT Compiler exceptions in the console

Tags: angular

I have a very simple angular `widget` that fits into an existing HTML page. It has only one component inside which I have a few SELECT fields. Everything worked fine until I decided to use `SplitChunks` plugin of webpack to split all the `node_modules` stuff into a separate vendor bundle and include it separately.

My application is not using any builder, it was never built using any building tool such as `angular-cli`. I built it from scratch, wrote my own main.ts, module.ts, and app.component.ts, and wrote my own webpack.config.js.

The error I got at runtime was

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Errors during JIT compilation of template for AppComponent: Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch. ("
                <label class="cs-label">User:</label>
            </td>
            [ERROR ->]{{firstname}}
            <td>
                <select [(ngModel)]="user.id" id="ddlUser" name="ddlC"): /Angular/UserWidget/app.component.html@43:3 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Errors during JIT compilation of template for AppComponent: Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch. ("
                <label class="cs-label">User:</label>
            </td>
            [ERROR ->]{{firstname}}
            <td>
                <select [(ngModel)]="user.id" id="ddlUser" name="ddlC"): /Angular/UserWidget/app.component.html@43:3
    at parseJitTemplate (compiler.mjs:19736:1)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileComponent (compiler.mjs:19448:43)
    at AppComponent.get (core.mjs:22739:1)
    at getComponentDef (core.mjs:1152:1)
    at verifyDeclarationsHaveDefinitions (core.mjs:22329:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.mjs:22300:1)
    at AppModule.get (core.mjs:22248:1)
    at getInjectorDef (core.mjs:421:1)
```

I experimented with the problem and tried to isolate it and here are some interesting findings.

There were a couple of interpolation bindings like the following

```
{{ firstName }}
```

I changed the above to the following and it started working :)

```
<span [innerText]="firstName" ></span>
```

I added all sorts of crazy things such as `*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, `banana-in-the-box bindings [()]`  and no compiler errors. As soon as there is an interpolation used, it starts to fail in the bootstrap process.

What cold cause interpolation to fail with Sys.ParameterCountException?

Any lead on what should I check, or any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: Angular 15 isn't compatible with .NET Framework 4.8 web applications.

Posting this answer here in case someone else runs into this in the future.

I had an ASP.NET Web Forms application where Angular 15 app fit inside a page as a widget. I used the following troubleshooting steps to narrow it down to one ASP.NET Web Forms assembly called `System.Web.Extensions`.

### Troubleshooting

First I copied the entire rendered HTML from the browser's debugging tools and turned it into a static HTML page that fits my widget. I was able to reproduce the problem on that page.

Then I started removing stuff from the page one by one, with the goal to leave only the problematic part along with the angular widget. I kept on removing until my removal made the widget work fine, in that case I knew what was causing it and added it back.

Turns out that the assembly `System.Web.Extensions` was adding a script tag like the following

I pasted the URL in the src in the browser to download the script and I found that the script was basically a kind of polyfills which was changing a lot of native scripting environment stuff such as the prototypes of intrinsic types.

One of which was the change in `string.startsWith()` method in which the polyfills was overriding it to check the parameter count in the `startsWith` call and was expecting only one parameter.

`@angular/compiler` library was using the new `ES6` version of startsWith that accepts an extra `index` parameter but since the implementation was overriden, the polyfills implementation was throwing error saying there were too many parameters specified.

### The Hack

This is a really bad hack, I am not happy about it. Someone please suggest me a better alternative.

At the beginning of the page execution I made a backup of the startsWith implementatoin in a global variable like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var prototypeStringStartsWith = string.prototype.startsWith;
</script>
```

Before I included the angular app scripts, I added a `Restore` sequence to restore the implementation from the backup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  string.prototype.startsWith = prototypeStringStartsWith;
</script>
```

The app is now working.